# RS232 Splitter Capable of Transmitting/Receiving data to one device and only Transmitting to another

Tags: serial, communication, rs232, port

I was wondering if it is possible to have a RS232 splitter that is able to split the data into two RS232 connections, and allow for one of the connects to still be able to transmit data back through the splitter to the source.

So the problem that I am having which has led to this question is that I have data coming from an ECU in my rallycross car, via an RS232 cable, and I need to split this data. One device is a RF transceiver to stream the data to a laptop, this device would need to be able to receive and transmit data to the ECU. The other device is a DAQ system that then feeds into a driver display, the DAQ only needs to receive data and does not need to transmit back to the ECU.

Comment: Something like this maybe? http://www.bb-elec.com/Products/Serial-Connectivity/Serial-Data-Tools-Adapters/Port-Splitters.aspx

Comment: Does the following help, it sounds like pretty much what you're after just you'd only need one side for sending data to the DAQ: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/63865/rs-232-serial-sniffing/

Comment: @PeterJ Thank you, I think that if I combine that post you linked with the answer from alex.forencich I will have a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, something like this?

```
TX1 ------- RX2
RX1 ---+--- TX2
       |
       +--- RX3
```

where TX1/RX1 is the ECU, TX2/RX2 is the radio transceiver, and RX3 is the DAQ?  That should work just fine, presuming all of the voltage levels are identical.  You'll probably need to make a cable or adapter for this, though, but it's completely passive - just connectors and wires.